# Magento 2: Get Product URL and SKU using SQL Query

Tags: magento-2.1, sql, query

How can I get all SKUs and Product URLs using only SQL Query?

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not save product URLs completely in database tables. It saves only **URL key**, so you can get **SKU** and **URL key** directly from tables.

**SKU** is saved in **`catalog_product_entity`** table.

By default product's **URL key** is an attribute which is of type varchar, so its value is saved in **`catalog_product_entity_varchar`** table. By default attribute id of product's URL key is 124.

Please let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: The catalog_product_entity table does not contain URL key in 2.1.7 .However, how can we construct the complete URL from the URL key?

Comment: I think all the URLs are available in the url_rewrite table. Now the question comes in how to link this URL with the SKU.

Comment: Yes, you are going in right direction.

Comment: You can get ID from sku and then get url from url rewrite table using path.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am joining the two tables as explained by Mohit, you can pass the attribute_id directly as well.

```
select e.entity_id,e.sku,v.value from catalog_product_entity e
inner join catalog_product_entity_varchar v on e.entity_id = v.entity_id and 
attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'url_key' and entity_type_id = 4)
```

If you want to append .html part to url:

```
select e.entity_id,e.sku,CONCAT(v.value,'.html') as url from catalog_product_entity e
inner join catalog_product_entity_varchar v on e.entity_id = v.entity_id and 
attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'url_key' and entity_type_id = 4)
```